# How to convert Gregorian date (date picker) to Shamsi?

Tags: c#, datetimepicker, persian-calendar

I use a date picker as an input for selected date. I want to convert the selected date into its equivalent Shamsi (persian) date. I tried this code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] Gregorian = Convert.ToString(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString()).Split('/');
        PersianCalendar persian = new PersianCalendar();
        label4.Text = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", persian.GetYear(Convert.ToInt32(Gregorian[2]), persian.GetMonth(Convert.ToInt32(Gregorian[0]), persian.GetDayOfMonth(Convert.ToInt32(Gregorian[1])));
    }
```

But it has red underline in `Convert.ToInt32(Gregorian[1])` section. The IDE says "cannot convert from 'int' to 'system.DateTime'.
Please help me.

Comment: Please provide any errors the IDE reports as text. "It has a red underline" is not a good bug report.

Comment: A calendar takes DateTimes for the used Get Day/Month/Year method. But you take a Datetime make a string out of it and make an int out of it. Simply fill dateTimePicker1.Value into those methods.

Comment: The IDE says "cannot convert from 'int' to 'system.DateTime'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this:

```
       private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        PersianCalendar persian = new PersianCalendar();
        label4.Text = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", persian.GetYear(dateTimePicker1.Value), persian.GetMonth(dateTimePicker1.Value), persian.GetDayOfMonth(dateTimePicker1.Value));
    }
```